# scipy - Generate many two-sample t statistics using bootstrap

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have the following `pandas.DataFrame` stored in `df`:

| female | income |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 23351.1 |
| 1 | 357.05 |
| 1 | 20385.2 |
| 0 | 12049.2 |

I want to use `scipy.stats.bootstrap` to calculate 1,000 *t* statistics comparing the mean income of men and women.

To generate a single *t* statistic, I would do:

```py
# Import `stats`
from scipy import stats as st
# Get t-statistic
t = st.ttest_ind(df.loc[df['female'].eq(0), 'income'],
                 df.loc[df['female'].eq(1), 'income'])[0]
```

I was wondering if `scipy.stats.bootstrap` can be used to generate 1,000 such statistics.

I tried:

```
# Arrays for each group
f = df.loc[df['female'].eq(0), 'income'].values
m = df.loc[df['female'].eq(1), 'income'].values

# Wild attempt
st.bootstrap(data=[f, m], statistic=st.ttest_ind)
```

> ValueError: `method = 'BCa' is only available for one-sample statistics

Here's a replicable example of `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'female': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0},
 'income': {0: 23351.08,
  1: 357.04999,
  2: 20385.221,
  3: 12049.17,
  4: 20541.619,
  5: 13206.52,
  6: 17055.73,
  7: 60442.621,
  8: 4499.9902,
  9: 37663.039}})
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bootstrap.html) for `bootstrap` says "bootstrap can also be used to estimate confidence intervals of multi-sample statistics, including those calculated by hypothesis tests" and "To get a confidence interval for the test statistic, we first wrap [the test statistic] in a function that accepts two sample arguments, accepts an axis keyword argument, and returns only the statistic."  There is an example.